# Как отследить ошибки 404?

Tags: php, логирование, error404

Нужна возможность отслеживать ошибки 404 и записывать их в бд (id, url, date)
как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Error URL**

```
    $get_url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 

"https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 

"http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

**Get Date Time**

```
$get_date = date("l, F d, Y g:i A T");
```

**Get IP Address**

```
$get_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

**Get User Agent**

```
$get_user = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

После того, как вы записали эти значения в переменные PHP, вы можете написать код, чтобы вставить их в базу данных MySQL или отправить электронное письмо на нужный адрес электронной почты.

**Store in MySQL Database**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","LOGIN_ID","PASSWORD");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("YOUR_DB", $con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME (error_type, ip_address, date_time, user_agent, error_url)
VALUES ('Page Not Found - 404 Error','$get_ip','$get_date','$get_user','$get_url')");
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать довольно просто -  **фиксация запроса отсутствующего `url`**  - получение запроса, проверка на наличие в базе адреса, запись в базу с нужными параметрами - например, самого запрошенного `url`, времени запроса, `ip`.

Все необходимые скрипты для фиксации располагать в точке/точках входа - приводить примеры кода не стоит, думается, поскольку не соответствует правилам, да и вариации могут быть - в соответствии с Вашими потребностями и существующего кода сайта.